# Automatically display echo result in terminal as pretty printed JSON

Tags: json, macos, terminal

I'm working on a PHP script where I'm returning a result that is a JSON array. Usually once I get my result in Terminal I then manually type:

`echo '{the result}' | python -m json.tool`

Is there any way to do this in my code so when it runs it prints the return automatically structured?

Here's the code:

```
$data = json_encode($data);                                                                   
   $ch = curl_init($url);                                                                        
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                              
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                               
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                   
       'Content-Type: application/json',                                                         
       'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
       'Expect: '
   ));                                                                                           
                                                                                                 
   $result = curl_exec($ch);                                                                     
   curl_close($ch);                                                                              
                                                                                                 
   echo $result;
```

$result returns something like this after the code is ran:

```
{"result":{"opportunity":[{"id":"6579732483","ownerID":"313505310","dealStageID":"434077699","accountID":"10363064323","campaignID":"808040451","opportunityName":"Opp 1","probability":"10","amount":"10000","isClosed":"0","isWon":"0","closeDate":"2020-06-30 00:00:00","createTimestamp":"2020-06-08 16:11:37","originatingLeadID":"719186417667","isActive":"1","primaryLeadID":"721297804291","opportunity_field_5ed6d251540e0":null,"opp_field_2_5ee13dbbe9394":null,"image_link_1_5ee1648e3764a":null,"image_link_2_5ee164a2e1929":null,"image_link_3_5ee164b251037":null}]},"error":null,"id":"","callCount":"12","queryLimit":"50000"}
```

I've tried just wrapping the $result in JSON_PRETTY_PRINT but this returns with / characters in the return which doesn't print how I want in Terminal.

As per suggestion I have encoded the response in JSON and then pass JSON_PRETTY_PRINT like so:

```
$result = json_encode(curl_exec($ch),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

However, this just seems to add the / characters which won't display as formatted new lines:

```
"{\"result\":{\"opportunity\":[{\"id\":\"6579732483\",\"ownerID\":\"313505310\",\"dealStageID\":\"434077699\",\"accountID\":\"10363064323\",\"campaignID\":\"808040451\",\"opportunityName\":\"Opp 1\",\"probability\":\"10\",\"amount\":\"10000\",\"isClosed\":\"0\",\"isWon\":\"0\",\"closeDate\":\"2020-06-30 00:00:00\",\"createTimestamp\":\"2020-06-08 16:11:37\",\"originatingLeadID\":\"719186417667\",\"isActive\":\"1\",\"primaryLeadID\":\"721297804291\",\"opportunity_field_5ed6d251540e0\":null,\"opp_field_2_5ee13dbbe9394\":null,\"image_link_1_5ee1648e3764a\":null,\"image_link_2_5ee164a2e1929\":null,\"image_link_3_5ee164b251037\":null}]},\"error\":null,\"id\":\"\",\"callCount\":\"25\",\"queryLimit\":\"50000\"}"
```

Is there no way to just have this print automatically like the following:

```
{
    "callCount": "26",
    "error": null,
    "id": "",
    "queryLimit": "50000",
    "result": {
        "opportunity": [
            {
                "accountID": "10363064323",
                "amount": "10000",
                "campaignID": "808040451",
                "closeDate": "2020-06-30 00:00:00",
                "createTimestamp": "2020-06-08 16:11:37",
                "dealStageID": "434077699",
                "id": "6579732483",
                "image_link_1_5ee1648e3764a": null,
                "image_link_2_5ee164a2e1929": null,
                "image_link_3_5ee164b251037": null,
                "isActive": "1",
                "isClosed": "0",
                "isWon": "0",
                "opp_field_2_5ee13dbbe9394": null,
                "opportunityName": "Opp 1",
                "opportunity_field_5ed6d251540e0": null,
                "originatingLeadID": "719186417667",
                "ownerID": "313505310",
                "primaryLeadID": "721297804291",
                "probability": "10"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you’ve got some server response that you want to pretty printed, you’ll probably want to decode the JSON and then print that in a pretty format (e.g. you could re-encode with pretty print option).

Comment: @Rob It is a server response. The response is being pre-encoded within the $data variable. 

$data = json_encode($data);

Are you saying I should remove json_encode or change it to json_decode after it's encoded and then JSON_PRETTY_PRINT?

Comment: Try using `jq` - A JSON syntax aware shell tool to manipulate and pretty print JSON - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I’m saying that if `$result`, which is presumably the server response that is JSON that isn’t pretty printed, you’ll want to decode it and then re-encode to JSON again, this time with pretty print option.

Comment: Rob, Okay I've done that:
  $result = json_encode(curl_exec($ch),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

However this just prints the results in Terminal with "/" characters in it. Is there not a way to display formatted?